# How to make const variables filled at runtime accessible across all of the program?

Tags: c++, static

What technique should I use to make a list of `const` variables whose value is known only at runtime accessible across all of the program?

Yes, I can make it in a way like that:

```
class some
{
    static const int a;
    static const int b;
    ...
    static const int z;
};

int some::a(f1());
int some::b(f2());
...
int some::z(f3());
```

And I guess it will work fine... But what if there are many such variables? In such a case there must be a lot of corresponding functions, and I don't find this solution elegant.

Have you got any ideas?

Comment: where are the values coming from?

Comment: Use a _Singleton Class_ to keep all the member variables private, and expose them publicly through (const) getters.

Comment: @idclev463035818 For example from a keyboard.

Comment: You can't call them `const` if they will be assigned at run-time.  See also the keyword `mutable`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Wait, what do you mean "call `const`"? The code snipped above works fine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Weep; recommending the singleton *anti pattern* :-(  That crap has bitten me more times than I want to admit and these days I avoid singletons like the plague. There are just *so many* issues - tight coupling, the whole static initialization fiasco mess, problems during destruction after `main` and so, so much more. Better to just not go there, it always ends in tears. Singleton == bad (IMHO).

Comment: @Jesper Well, a singleton can be considered as anti pattern if done wrong. It's not unusual to use these as _registries_, _registrars_, _repositories_ whatever you name it. All kind of dependency injection mechanisms are kept through singletons in the very end. And it's of course better than keeping a bunch of global public variables.

Comment: @TheMathWay How does one modify a `static const` member in a struct? (during run-time).  I know it can be done in the constructor.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You don't modify it obviously. You start the program, and initialize it with the value at runtime in the constructor. Just like the code above already does.

Comment: @TheMathWay , I updated my answer please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know many won't like this, because *Singletons* are considered bad design, anti patterns and whatnot. Though *Singletons* are ubiquituous in many framework and architectural designs.

That said, now for the OPs question:

> But what if there are many such variables? In such a case there must be a lot of corresponding functions, and I don't find this solution elegant.

First of all you shouldn't stray these values over the global space (even not if appearing in a `struct`).

What you can do instead:

```
class MyConfiguration {
public:
     static const MyConfiguration& instance() {
         static MyConfiguration theInstance;
         return theInstance;
     }
     int a() const { return a_; }
     int b() const { return b_; }
     int c() const { return c_; }

private:
     MyConfiguration() : a_(0), b_(0), c_(0) {
         loadConfigValues();
     }

     void loadConfigValues() {
         a_ = 42;
         b_ = getFromElseWhere();
         c_ = a_ * b_;
     }

     int a_;
     int b_;
     int c_;
};
```

Your constants will be loaded once, and are accessible using

```
int y = MyConfiguration::instance().a();
int bar = MyConfiguration::instance().b();
```

You'll still need a lot of getter functions this way, but it's better maintainable, and guaranteed to be used only from one access point.

---

<sub>Just before someone comes mentioning the *"static initialization order fiasco"* or thread safety of instantiation, the above implementation overcomes these problems.</sub>

Comment: `instance` is a function, so when we do such a thing as `int y = MyConfiguration::instance.a()`, shouldn't we append () after `instantce`? By the way, why here everybody says that Singleton is an antipattern, but nevertheless provide it as a solution for the problem. What problems does it have?

Comment: @TheMathWay 1. Yes, sorry. There is another pair of `()` needed. I fixed that. 2. That _Singleton_ is an anti-pattern is a myth, because a) It's hard (not really) to get it right, and b) hurts your overall design / architecture if overused and abused. Having a _Singleton_ for application wide configuration is a common and wide spread use. People tend to disguise their singletons with fancy names like _Registry_ or _Registrar_, etc. because they don't want to argue about that old mysticism, that casted such a bad slur on that still valid and useful pattern.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, you can use an array:

`std::array<int> params;`

or

`std::array<std::any> params`

if they are of different type. I'm assuming you want to have an uniform interface.

As for the scope, making the list global or making it a singleton would certainly work, but you gotta be very very careful. If you have many functions using those variables, perhaps wrapping them in a class would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested using singleton is a grand solution for your problem. But if you need a simpler one and if only managing large number of uniform constants and functions is what you are after you can use it inside templates like this:

```
template<long number>
int const_filler(int v){
    return number * v;
};

template<long number>
struct const_holder{
    static const long value;
};

template<long number>
const int const_holder<number>::value = const_filler< number>(2);

int main()
{
    std::cout << const_holder<2>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the constants are

```
const_holder<0>::value
const_holder<1>::value
const_holder<2>::value
.
.
.
```

And they are filled at the first usage.

With this method you can have as many (actually as many as long integers that processor supports) constants and functions as you want. if you want a version which you can also choose the type of the constant then you can use the following:

```
template<typename type, long number>
type const_filler(int v){
    return number * v;
};

template<typename type, long number>
struct const_holder{
    static const type value;
};

template<typename type, long number>
const type const_holder<type, number>::value = const_filler<type, number>(2);

int main()
{
    std::cout << const_holder<int, 2>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TheMathWay  No, it also works for float constants and user defined types. only the index should be of integer types.